# Angular 5 authentication with Okta in Electron

Tags: angular, electron, angular5, openid-connect, okta

Im trying to configure my angular app authentication part, but i'm failing to make it work inside of Electron since i'm loading my angular app from a html file instead of loading it inside a local server. What is the best approach to tackle this issue ? I'm using angular-oauth2-oidc library for this task, the authentication works fine when i launch the angular app on the browser directly with `ng serve` since the redirect url is set to localhost:4200, but with Electron it doesn't work since it is not hosted on a local server.

Comment: You could try our Auth SDK and build the login form yourself. I show how to do that, and integrate with angular-oauth2-oidc in this blog post: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/08/22/build-an-ionic-app-with-user-authentication

Comment: @MattRaible Thanks, i actually followes your tutorial to configure everything because i wanted to test the concept. In the end im going to switch to Identityserver 4 thats why i need to find a solution on how to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Electron I'd recommend using the correct OAuth flow for a desktop app, according to the [Auth0 web site](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/which-oauth-flow-to-use), which is **'Authorization Code (PKCE)'**.

Your Angular OIDC library is for Single Page Applications, which use a different solution called **'Implicit Flow'**.

The technique for Desktop Apps is to trigger a login on the System Browser, but it is tricky and more work than you'd probably like.

There is an [Electron AppAuth Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/appauth-js-electron-sample) that does desktop logins:

- During user logins, there is a switch to the System Browser
- After login completes the desktop app is notified
- The notification is via either **Loopback Interface** or **Private URI Scheme**

I've been writing a very detailed blog on OAuth technologies that you may want to browse: it includes some notes on [Desktop Logins](http://authguidance.com/2018/01/11/desktop-apps-overview/).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I have been actually working on that AppAuth Sample and managed to make it work in my app. The only issues im facing now are:
• Saving the token and managing it.
• Opening the login page in a new electron window instead of the system browser, do you know if thats achievable ? Or does it require me to modify the AppAuth library ? I also don&#39;t like the &quot;Close this window&quot; page as i would like to design something more polished or just destroy the window automatically with Electron.

Comment: @IsaacSalem how were you able to handle the redirect? I have been using the appauth-js lib in my angular app... i recently moved my angular app into electron.. but the one thing I cant get working is the redirect back... localhost just seems to fail.. again its probably as you said earlier, the angular app is not served locally.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to use a new Electron Window if you replace the default **NodeBasedHandler**- see [This Code from StupidUglyFool](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-JS/issues/29) - he's a smart guy who's posted some good stuff.

**ELECTRON WINDOW LOGIN PROBLEMS**

I started down that road as well - it will work but the Electron Window is effectively a Web View with a Private Browser Session and you will have these problems:

- Password Autofill will not work when users login
- Single Sign On across more than one desktop app will not work

Also logging on via Electron Windows is not considered right in security terms - some providers such as Google will block logins.

**SYSTEM BROWSER LOGINS**

If you are interested there are a couple of my samples on GitHub here that may help you:

- [Logins via Loopback Interface](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.desktopsample1)
- [Login via Private URI Scheme](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.desktopsample.final)

These both replace the NodeBasedHandler under **desktopapp/src/plumbing**, so you can maybe borrow ideas from them. Also both code samples link to write ups with some screenshots etc.

**NONE OF THE OPTIONS ARE PERFECT**

Unfortunately no option is perfect and you need to make your own choice based on trade offs between usability / security / complexity.